# egrep matching expressions with wildcard

Tags: regex, bash, grep, wildcard

Going through some exercises, got stuck on this one:

```
egrep "s*as" states.txt

## Alaska
## Arkansas
## Kansas
## Massachusetts
## Nebraska
```

I can understand why it selects Arkansas, Kansas, Massachusetts, but why Alaska? There should have been the first "s" from "s*as", should it not? Am I missing something in plain sight? Sorry if the answer is obvious, I don't get it. grep gives the same results.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a regexp tutorial. Go to www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: Regular expressions are not the same as filename wildcards.

Comment: see also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `egrep` below:

```
egrep "s*as" states.txt
```

The quantity `s*` means match `s` *zero* or more times.  Hence, `Alaska` matches because it contains `as`.  If you intend to match `s`, followed by any single character, followed by `as` then use dot:

```
egrep "s.as" states.txt
```

---

Note that there is a difference between filename wildcards and regular expressions.

`*` in regular expression, quoting [GNU Grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Fundamental-Structure.html#Fundamental-Structure):

> The preceding item will be matched zero or more times

`*` in filename wildcard, quoting [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

> Matches any string, including the null string

Comment: @PesaThe Feel free to edit my answer.  The only way I can explain the OP's observations is that the `*` is quantifying the preceding `s`.